# SQL TRIGGER THE MULTI-PART IDENTIFIER CANT BE BOUND

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, syntax-error

I am very new to programming.  I am trying to teach myself SQL.  I made a video store database with a customer, rental, and inventory table.  I am looking at examples online to try to LEARN SQL, so please be kind.  I want this trigger to stop a person from renting the same movie at the same time.  I have been reading up on triggers and would like some help with the code below.

I am getting syntax errors on the last END, a syntax error on RAISEERROR, and INSERTED. I am also still getting the message "Trigger multipart identifier cannot be bound" on i.Rental.rentNum inserted i;

Any help will be much appreciated!

```
CREATE TRIGGER
insteadOFInsert ON Rental
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
DECLARE @rentNum int, @action varchar(60) 

SELECT @Rent_rentNum=i.Rental.rentNum inserted i;
SET  @action='stop rental trigger.'
     @Rent_rentNum=(SELECT rentNum FROM inserted; 

BEGIN
   BEGIN TRAN
     SET NOCOUNT ON
       IF (@RENT_rentNum=Rental.rentNum)
         BEGIN 
           RAISEERROR ('You cannot rent the same move twice');
           ROLLBACK
         END
       ELSE 
        BEGIN 
          INSERT INTO
           Rental(rentNum)
                  VALUES
                (@rentNum)
           INSERT INTO 
              Rent values (rentNum);
           COMMIT
           PRINT 'Updated'
        END
       END
```

Comment: if you see, your formatted code, its not complete, one end missing?

Comment: `INSERT INTO 
    Rent(rentNum)...` This is incomplete

Comment: and also your insert statement incomelete with table

Comment: no, still a problem.  same errors :(

Comment: do you have any suggestions, @Mihai

Comment: im using sql management studio 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger has several **fundamental** flaws:

- please ***never ever*** use `BEGIN TRAN` inside a trigger! The trigger is running in the context of the statement that caused it to fire, and therefore is *already* in the context of a transaction
- you need to be aware that the trigger will be called **once per statement** - not once per row! So if your `INSERT` statement inserts 10 rows, your trigger is fired **once**, and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain **10 rows** of data - which one do you think will be picked in your statement

  ```
  SELECT rentNum FROM inserted;
  ```

  One of them will do - one more or less at random - and the 9 others will be ignored.

So basically, you need to totally rewrite your trigger to something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insteadOFInsert 
ON dbo.Rental
AFTER INSERT
AS
    // if any one of the rows inserted already exists in the Rental table -> abort
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Rental WHERE RentNum IN (SELECT RentNum FROM Inserted))
    BEGIN        
        RAISEERROR ('You cannot rent the same move twice');
        ROLLBACK
    END
```

You didn't explain why you had picked to use an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger - I really don't see any good reason for that, so I chose to do this as an `AFTER INSERT` trigger instead (it's just plain simpler to write these)

Comment: THANK YOU.  Your suggestion was simple and effective.  I am still learning SQL, so I have a lot to go over.  thank you again, sir!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `values` from second insert statement. Try This

```
  INSERT INTO  Rent values (@rentNum);
```

**[EDIT]**

```
DECLARE @Rent_rentNum int
  SET @Rent_rentNum = (SELECT rentNum FROM inserted);
```

and also match each Open and close `BEGIN` & `END`

Comment: Is your current trigger complied correctly?, if not then Try to add "END" at the end

Comment: I am getting syntax errors on the last END, a syntax error on RAISEERROR, and INSERTED.  I am also still getting the message "Trigger multipart identifier cannot be bound" on i.Rental.rentNum inserted i;

Comment: use updated lines where you are setting variable value in your trigger

Comment: you also have to use @rentNum in line INSERT INTO Rent values (rentNum)

Comment: I am using a VM with SQL on a mac, so I have been changing the code and copy paste isn't something i can easily do.  Is this what you mean? @Piyush

Comment: just asking, are you able to fixed the issue with suggested changes or issue still persist?

Comment: try to copy paste correctly, you are missing closing bracket in @Rent_rentNum=(SELECT rentNum FROM inserted;   try to read first http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your first SELECT is missing a FROM before "inserted".

Comment: Yes, I was missing the From before inserted (it was a typo--my code is in a VM that I cannot copy and paste from with my mac).  Im still really struggling with "Trigger multipart identifier cannot be bound" on i.Rental.rentNum inserted i;